# My IBM server X 3400 stops suddenly and it does not power up?

Tags: ibm

My IBM server X 3400 shut down suddenly one fine day. When I use the power switch to power it on, it starts and then shuts down without any sign of flaws.  When I took off the power cords and then I reconnected after 2 minutes it started and then shut down after a minute.  Why does this happen?

Comment: Can you describe what it does? It prints something (what) in the screen? Does it show the  boot loader? It gets to boot or start booting the operating system?

Comment: Is it very hot where you are today?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have a hardware failure (it could be a lot of things, from the power supply to the system board onward; I've even seen a bad disk cause this).

You probably have a support contract you can take advantage of in this case.